# Ant design Table does not re-render using Nextjs

Tags: render, next.js, antd

I have a working Table component in a Nextjs app that only renders the first time but if I change the data it doesn't update.

```
render() {
  const data = this.props.data
  console.log(data) // this shows the new data changing in the console but the table doesn't update

  return (
    <Table dataSource={data} columns={this.state.columns} />
  )
}
```

The same version it works OK using Create React App
Thanks in advance

Update:
Now works if I change the data to force array modification with:

```
const data = this.props.data.slice(0,this.props.data.length)
```

Is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: How are you updating the data?

Comment: you can not change props directly, read the react documentation

Comment: The data comes from the state of the parent component, passed through props. Once the parent state is updated you can see the new data making a console.log on the children render, but the Table component do not use the new one (unles I make the new array).